# How to convert a decimal to a fraction than convert the result to a text?

Tags: excel, decimal, fractions

In this case I have a series of dimensions that need to be converted for upload into another database.

21.3 x 16.9 x 14.6

Needs to become

21 5/16 x 16 14/16 x 14 10/16

I can split up the numbers and reformat that into the correct fractions, but this is only for display in that cell. If you click on the cell itself, you can see in the task bar that they remain decimals.

How do I make the change permanent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basicall you will need to save them as text.  Use the TEXT formula:

```
TEXT(A1,"# ??/16")
```

Which will change the decimal in A1 to a fraction.

To do the whole in one formula TEXTJOIN() as an Array Formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" x ",TRUE,TEXT(--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"x",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW($1:$3)-1)*99+1,99)),"# ??/16"))
```

Being an Array Formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

TEXTJOIN was introduced with Office 365 Excel.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to a cell other than the one holding your decimal value and use this formula:

`=TEXT(A1,"# ??/??")`

where `A1` is the cell holding your decimal value. Now copy the cell holding that formula, and then right-click, paste **Values** (it looks like a *123* on a clipboard). You can do this right over the formula or in a new cell. That should retain the formatting the way you want.