# How to convert inches with decimals to feet and inches

Tags: excel, decimal, formula, fractions

I have an Excel spreadsheet with the following data in A1 and A2(column is formatted as Text).

```
  A
1 258.1875
2 294.1875
```

I need the data to display in B1 and B2 in feet and inches, like this: (column needs to be formatted as Text).

```
  B
1 21'-6 3/16"     that is 21'-6space3/16"
2 22'-10 3/16"
```

Can someone provide a formula which will do this?

This is how I'm currently doing this:  I'm splitting the inches and the decimals into 2 columns

Example:

```
258 in column B1        .1875 in Column C1.  I multiply column A1 by 12 to get:
21.5  in B1,            .1875 in column C1
```

Then I insert a column for the new decimal so I now have`

```
21 in B1                  .5 in C1          .18875 in D1
We concat with ' in B1    multiply by 12     convert to fraction
```

Now I have

```
21" in B1                 6 in C1            3/16 in D1
```

I concatenate the 3 fields, adding a dash before and a space after the 6, and the inches symbol after the 3/16 in C1 which gives me

```
21'-6 3/16"
```

It's a lot of work and I have to do this for up to 1000 lines at a time, so an Excel formula would save me so much time!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a decimal to a fraction than convert the result to a text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53177935/how-to-convert-a-decimal-to-a-fraction-than-convert-the-result-to-a-text)

Comment: Does the fraction need to be reduced? What if it's exactly 2 feet? Should it be represented as `2'-0 0/16"`? or just `2'`?

Comment: Andreas, you are a lifesaver!  It worked perfectly.

Thank you so much!  :)

Connie

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
=INT(INT(A1)/12) & "'-" & MOD(INT(A1),12) & " " & TEXT(MOD(A1,1),"??/16") & """"
```

[image]

If you want to omit the fraction if there is none:

```
=INT(INT(A1)/12) & "'-" & MOD(INT(A1),12) & IF(MOD(A1,1)>0,TEXT(MOD(A1,1)," ??/16"),"") & """"
```

[image]